# Grails spring security toString not working on extending GrailsUser

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security

I have implemented my own UserDetailsService which is returning MyGrailsUser instance in the loadUserByUsername method.
The MyGrailsUser class extends GrailsUser class and here it is:

```
class MyGrailsUser extends GrailsUser{
    /**
     * Constructor.
     *
     * @param username the username presented to the
     *        <code>DaoAuthenticationProvider</code>
     * @param password the password that should be presented to the
     *        <code>DaoAuthenticationProvider</code>
     * @param enabled set to <code>true</code> if the user is enabled
     * @param accountNonExpired set to <code>true</code> if the account has not expired
     * @param credentialsNonExpired set to <code>true</code> if the credentials have not expired
     * @param accountNonLocked set to <code>true</code> if the account is not locked
     * @param authorities the authorities that should be granted to the caller if they
     *        presented the correct username and password and the user is enabled. Not null.
     * @param id the id of the domain class instance used to populate this
     */
    MyGrailsUser(String username, String password, boolean enabled, boolean accountNonExpired, boolean credentialsNonExpired, boolean accountNonLocked, Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities, Object id) {
        super(username, password, enabled, accountNonExpired, credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked, authorities, id)
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.username
    }
}
```

Now when I am calling the spring security's `springSecurityService.getPrincipal().toString()` 
I get this exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: security.userdetails.MyGrailsUser cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

Why am I getting this exception even after overriding the toString() method of MyGrailsUser?

Comment: Did you `clean` and `compile --non-interactive --refresh-dependencies` before `run-app`?

Comment: Seems like it's trying to do "(return this).username" instead of "return (this.username)"  Any particular reason you have "this" in that line?   Could just be "return username" and you're done

Comment: What happens when you don't implement toString()?  Does the exception still get thrown?

Comment: @NickHammond yeah!

Comment: @rahulserver can you add the code that is calling the getPrincipal().toString()